# A continuous function defined on all of R with range equal to subset of Q

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was considering the function

$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\lfloor{xn}\rfloor$

this function obviously has rational numbers as output for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then I defined
$$f(x):=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)$$

the graph then looks like $f(x)=x$

Then I proved its continuity

$$\forall\epsilon>0, let\,  \delta=\epsilon , such\, that\,    |x-c|<\delta$$
We have

Case $1$, $x>c$

$$\Big|\frac{1}{n}\lfloor{xn}\rfloor-\frac{1}{n}\lfloor{cn}\rfloor\Big|=\frac{1}{n}(\lfloor{xn}\rfloor-\lfloor{cn}\rfloor)<\frac{1}{n}(xn-(cn-1))$$

$$=(x-c)+\frac{1}{n}<\delta+\frac{1}{n}=\delta_n\rightarrow \delta$$

Case $2$, $x<c$

$$\Big|\frac{1}{n}\lfloor{xn}\rfloor-\frac{1}{n}\lfloor{cn}\rfloor\Big|=\frac{1}{n}(\lfloor{cn}\rfloor-\lfloor{xn}\rfloor)<\frac{1}{n}(cn-(xn-1))$$

$$(c-x)+\frac{1}{n}<\delta+\frac{1}{n}=\delta_n\rightarrow \delta$$

However, this result violates the Intermediate value theorem. Because there are 'holes' in the irrationals of the range while the domain is connected

So I'm suspecting that there is something wrong with my proof.

Firstly I know it is true that $f_n(x)$ is rational for all $n$, doesn't mean it is rational
as $n$ goes to infinity. An easy example for me is $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\longrightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}$$
But I can't make sense of it in this case. I feel like it is because it is function converging instead of value converging so it's more abstract. I would be very grateful if someone can explain this to me

Moreover, is there some ways/ techniques that we can recognize whether a sequence of rational numbers converges to a rational number?

Thank you

Comment: Only constant functions. If $f$ is such that $f(a)=r_1$ and $f(b)=r_2$, with $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb{Q}$ rationals, then there is some irrational $r_1<s<r_2$. If $f$ is continuous, then the intermediate value theorem gives the existence of $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=s$.

Comment: Please include the actual question in the body of the question. If the question is as in the title, then the only continuous functions whose domain is R and whose range is a subset of Q are constant functions $f(x)=c$ where $c$ is rational.